# C# listview itemcheck or itemchecked event

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, listviewitem, selectedindexchanged

I have a listview with first column as checkbox for each item.

I wanted to add an itemcheck or itemchecked event when the user tick a box that trigger fires.

I have added to my code:

```
private void ListView1_ItemCheck1(object sender, 
System.Windows.Forms.ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
  MessageBox.Show("has been checked");
}
```

For some reason, the event does not seem to be triggering.

Also, I found out that `private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged` works when you click on one of the list items (as if you're selecting)

Have you come across this issue?

Comment: wait, what is the use of your checkbox? If you want to select the whole row, or multiple row, there's a property for a listview, fullrowselect and mutlirowselect just set the values to true

Comment: Did you register that event on your Form Load?

Comment: I don't think I have register the event in the form load. Can you please let me know how?

Answer (score 1):

I have answered my own question, I have added this:

```
this.listView1.ItemCheck += new ItemCheckEventHandler(listView1_ItemCheck);
```

and worked like magic.